# Trying to delete record from within a Details action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I use an Index action to show a list of records in a grid like structure. I also have a Delete button as one of the columns which allows the user to delete a particular row/record. This works well. I also have a Details link in each row to allow seeing an individual record.

Delete has its own HttpPost action. Details also has its own regular action.

Problem is I now want to add this Delete button code to the Details view, but I am using a notifier and the delete itself works, but the code shows the notifier (because there is a record==null check in the Details action). I cannot figure out how to get around that.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
    var myList = _repository.Table;
    // Nothing else relevant just displays list and sets up model
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ...
    var record = _repository.Get(id);

    // If I use the Delete action below then this will get called and fire;
    // I am trying to figure out how to avoid it firing when I use the Delete code
    // in the Details view (see .cshtml code below)
    if (record == null)
    {
    _myServices.Notifier.Warning
            (T("Request not found, please check the URL."));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var model = new myViewModel();
    model.Id = record.Id;
    // Pulling other records, nothing special

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    var item = _repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        _myServices.Notifier.Error(T("Inquiry not found."));
    }
    else
    {
        _myServices.Notifier.Information(T("Request deleted successfully."));
        _repository.Delete(item);
    }

    return this.RedirectLocal(returnUrl, "~/");
}
```

I am wondering whether or not I should create a separate action like DeleteDetails, but the record=null check in the Details action would still fire.

Here is the delete code in both the Index view and Details view:

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "MyAdmin", 
    new { area = "MyNameSpace" }, 
    FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "delete-form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryTokenOrchard()
        @Html.Hidden("id", Model.Id)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Context.Request.ToUrlString())
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    }
}
```

Maybe I should change the Details view delete code?

Any thoughts?

Comment: So your `Details` action is triggered because you are redirecting to it in your `Delete` action when you pass `Context.Request.ToUrlString()` for the `returnUrl` in your Details view.  It probably doesn't make sense to come back to the Details view for a record you just deleted because you will run into errors like this.  Usually I redirect back to the list in this situation.

Comment: @asymptoticFault The Delete action is being used for both the Index (where it works fine - so in the Index you hit the "delete" button and it returns to the Index with the message that it was deleted and it displays the updated list without the record that it was deleted) and the Details actions. However, I hacked together using the Delete in Details action, so you are right I am making a mistake. Sorry am not a programmer. Should I create a new Delete action specific to Details? Can you provide an answer with code for that? Or should I modify the existing code to account for that?

Comment: How about just redirecting back to the Index when you Delete from the Details action?  Just change the value of the hidden `returnUrl` in your `delete-form` to `Url.Action("Index")`.

Comment: Given that your Details action will redirect to Index when the record doesn't exist, it makes sense to do this when a record is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `Details` action is triggered because you are redirecting to it in your `Delete` action when you pass `Context.Request.ToUrlString()` for the `returnUrl` in your `Details` view. It probably doesn't make sense to come back to the `Details` view for a record you just deleted because you will run into errors like this.

How about just redirecting back to the `Index` when you `Delete` from the `Details` action? Just change the value of the hidden `returnUrl` in your `delete-form` to `Url.Action("Index")`.  Given that your `Details` action will redirect to `Index` when the record doesn't exist, it makes sense to do this when a record is deleted.